# How to adjust ViewRenderable to match AugmentedImage size?

Tags: kotlin, arcore, sceneform, android-augmented-reality

I'm making a small AR app on Android to detect GIFs from a snapshot and overlay the actual GIF using `AugmentedImages`, but I can't get the size of the `ViewRenderable` to match up with the detected image so it perfectly overlays.

I'm following the [AugmentedImages Sceneform sample](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/augmentedimage) from Google, changing it to Kotlin and using my own images manually added to the `AugmentedImageDatabase`.

Below is the closest I've been able to get, but it still doesn't match up completely. `gifView` is set with the `ViewRenderable.builder()` and uses a simple XML file, shown after the code block. I'm using Glide in the `.thenAccept` of the builder to load the correct GIF from a URL.

`AugmentedImageNode`

```
private var gifView: ViewRenderable? = null
...
fun setImageToNode(image: AugmentedImage) {
    anchor = image.createAnchor(image.centerPose)

    gifView?.sizer = FixedHeightViewSizer(image.extentZ)

    val pose = Pose.makeTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)
    val localPosition = Vector3(pose.tx(), pose.ty(), pose.tz())
    val centerNode = Node()
    centerNode.setParent(this)
    centerNode.localPosition = localPosition
    centerNode.localRotation = Quaternion(pose.qx(), 90f, -90f, pose.qw())
    centerNode.renderable = gifView
    centerNode.localScale = Vector3(image.extentX * 15f, image.extentZ * 30f, 1.0f)
}
```

`R.layout.image_item`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/easy_button" />
```

No error messages are appearing, but the rendered image does not match the size of the detected image. I would like this to be dynamic since obviously not every GIF has the same dimensions.

See [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CV8MD.jpg) and notice how the detected image is slightly larger and looks like it's making a border around the clearer rendered image? (Not related to this question, but my camera isn't autofocusing even though I set the correct configuration setting)

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to calculate the scale a little more accurately. I went with the approach of instead of trying to scale the size of the renderable/`ImageView` to fit the image, I would just change the "scale" of the world so that however many pixels wide the image was, it was the same size in meters as the detected augmented image. I basically had to figure out how many pixels would be in a meter if the augmented image was a certain size. Below is the code I am using:

```
val imageWidth = 400 // TODO Get actual width of image dynamically, just luck that GIPHY images are 400 pixels wide
val viewWidth = (imageWidth / image.extentX).toInt()
gifView?.sizer = DpToMetersViewSizer(viewWidth)

val pose = Pose.makeTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)
val localPosition = Vector3(pose.tx(), pose.ty(), pose.tz())
val centerNode = Node()
centerNode.setParent(this)
centerNode.localPosition = localPosition
centerNode.localRotation = Quaternion(pose.qx(), 90f, -90f, pose.qw())
centerNode.renderable = gifView
```

This gets the rendered GIF to be much closer to the actual size of the detected image. I'll keep looking for a better approach.